# Bourne Shell Script to print out last argument

Tags: shell, unix

Im trying to create a bourne shell script that will take 0 or more arugments and print out the last arugment, I am use to writing Java and im so confused by this, slowly starting to learn C.

Comment: "Bourne shell" (as per the title) or "Bourne Again Shell (bash)" (as per the tags)?

Comment: How do you print the last argument if 0 arguments are passed?

Comment: it should simply return nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lastArg=`echo $@ | awk '{print $NF}'`
```

Comment: #!/bin/sh
read args
echo "Enter args: $args"
set $args
lastArg=`echo $@ | awk '{print $NF}'`
echo $lastArg'

Comment: @BeagleBoy360 - Is this comment saying that you get it? Or are you correcting something?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to @Michael's solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "${@: -1}"
```

- `$@` is the array with all the parameters.
- `:` is used to split strings normally (you can try this with `echo "${USER: -1}"` to verify that it prints the last character of your user name), but can also be used for arrays to get the last *element*.
- The curly brackets are needed for the array indexing to work
- The quotes are simply good practice, to make the code more flexible in case you want to mix in other variables, or the value needs to be used in a statement which needs an empty string rather than nothing in case of no parameters (for example `if [ "${@: -1}" = "--help" ]`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short Bash script that will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "${!#}"
```

This is not a Bourne shell script, though. Args are not read from the keyboard with the `read` command. Instead they are supplied on the command line when running your script. For example, if you put this text in `script.sh` and run `./script.sh a b c d e` it will print:

```
e
```

Comment: I should note that at one point this question was tagged "bash".

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
last_arg=`echo $* | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev`;
echo $last_arg
```

Your question mentions C. In C its easier:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
     char *last_arg = argv[argc - 1];
     [...]
}
```

Comment: #!/bin/sh 
read args 
echo "Enter args: $args" 
last_arg=`echo $* | rev | cut -d " " -f1 | rev`;
echo $last_arg

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
eval lastarg='$'$#
echo last arg is $lastarg
```

This works with `/bin/sh` being `bash` or `dash`.

I am unable to test it with a "real" `/bin/sh`, whatever that would be.